# Use a sum of two values from different tables in MYSQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I know there are similar questions but I've been struggling with this for almost two days and can't make solutions given to questions to work.

I have two tables,  for clarity lets say they have following structure:

```
table1:
id, timestamp
1,  1481631111
2,  1481632222
3,  1481633333

table2:
id, extra_days
2,  2
3,  1
```

I need to select the most recent entry from `table1` where `timestamp` has not passed `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` even if added extra_days from `table2`. In other words, exclude rows if `timestamp + extra_days * 68400` is greater than `NOW`.

My latest attempt looks like this but the `WHERE` clause seems to be ignored:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.timestamp FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.timestamp + (68400 * COALESCE(t2.extra_days,0)) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an integer (the unix timestamp calculated by adding the number of seconds) to a date and time.

Try using UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.timestamp 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.timestamp + (68400 * COALESCE(t2.extra_days,0)) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SQL-DB Software you use, look at their function for date arithmetic. They may provide handy function for this, like mariadb does for dates:
[MariaDB ADDDATE Function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/adddate/)